# Update field as the same as field in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table

```
TICKET_ID   ASSIGN          TERM           ASSIGN_DATE          ASSIGN_MEMO OFFICER
5988085     ASSIGN-5        S1IIPF381   2015-09-01 08:28:04.000 NULL        NULL
5988085     RESOLVED-CLOSED S1IIPF381   2015-09-01 05:38:46.000 NULL        NULL
5988085     RESOLVED-CLOSED S1IIPF381   2015-09-01 08:28:04.000 NULL        NULL
```

with  an update clause

```
UPDATE PROBLEM
  SET assign = 'ASSIGN-2',
      ASSIGN_MEMO = '12345'
  WHERE assign_date ='2015-09-01 08:28:04.000'
    AND ticket_id = '5988085'
    AND assign = 'ASSIGN-5';
```

I need to update where `ASSIGN` as the same as `ASSIGN` in where clause. Is it possible?

Expected output

```
TICKET_ID   ASSIGN          TERM           ASSIGN_DATE          ASSIGN_MEMO OFFICER
5988085     ASSIGN-2        S1IIPF381   2015-09-01 08:28:04.000 12345       NULL
5988085     RESOLVED-CLOSED S1IIPF381   2015-09-01 05:38:46.000 NULL        NULL
5988085     RESOLVED-CLOSED S1IIPF381   2015-09-01 08:28:04.000 NULL        NULL
```

Comment: please  show expected output..

Comment: sorry but, Is update clause have an output ?

Comment: i mean output after update ..@touchy

Comment: The above update query can update the table.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: maybe my code in asp.net /vb.net was wrong thanks to you all

Comment: I think you wrote perfect query for your desire output...

Comment: Question seems to answer itself... It is possible, and your query looks correct.